# Essential reads for people interested in Actuary and Actuarial science

Tags: references

My girlfriend (B.B.A) is really interested in Actuarial science. She's looking at self teaching her self. She's good with basic math (Calculus 1 and 2) and stats

What are some of the essential sources she needs to read in order to learn and excel in the field?

Comment: Converted to community wiki.

Answer (score 4):

And for bedtime reading, "Against the Gods: The Remarkable Story of Risk" by Peter L. Bernstein. She'll find out how Lloyds of London started, among many other interesting bits. Highly recommended and only $13 from amazon.

Answer (score 2):

sources:

1) statistics upto ANOVA
2) probability upto Central limit theorem
3) Basic programming and data analysis skills
4) Familiarity with business economics
5) Financial mathematics

This is a verrry basic smattering of things that she needs to read.