# What are good resources on nonlife actuarial science as it is being applied in industry?

Tags: references, actuarial-science

I have already browsed my way through the book *Nonlife Actuarial Models: Theory, Methods and Evaluation* by Yiu-Kuen Tse and I am already familiar with nearly all of the underlying statistics in that book. However I don't know how relevant this book is to the state of the nonlife insurance industry.

What I would like to know is what are some recommendations for highly regarded books, journals, leading graduate level university programs, and other resources that do a great job of expressing nonlife actuarial models and practices that are currently used in industry as well as the problems the industry is currently facing.

I've already seen [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/essential-reads-for-people-interested-in-actuary-and-actuarial-science?rq=1) which seems to only cover foundational math. I am asking for information about specific models, such as claim frequency and credibility, as they are modeled in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked in the commercial insurance division of one of the larger insurance firms in CT, USA for a bit. Most of what we did was generalized linear models (glms). The majority of the material to understand that would be in the book by McCullough and Nelder (https://www.google.com/search?q=mccullough+and+nelder). We also used Tweedie models a fair bit and those are discussed in theory in the dispersion models book by Jorgenson (https://www.google.com/search?q=jorgensen+exponential+dispersion+models). The paper that is a top hit on google is a worthwhile read but not for the faint of heart and highly mathematical. We did play around with RandomForests and mixed models but they were never put into production because of fear of regulators saying we couldn't use them.